# Frame size difference before and after creating a video

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg, frame-size

I am creating a video from images using Opencv.

```
dim=(width, height)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'X264')
out_d = cv2.VideoWriter(save_path_depth,fourcc, fps, dim)
```

After creating video I read video and extract frames from that video

```
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret == False:
        break
    print(frame)
    cv2.imwrite(output+"/"+ str(i).zfill(1) + ".png", frame)      
    i+=1

cap.release()
```

Frame size is almost double than size of frame i initially used to create the video. Other than that when i do frame to frame comparison, some frames are completely different than their counterpart original frames. Can somebody explain what can be the reason behind it.

Comment: Hi, Do your images have the same size ? have you verified if the image sort by opencv is the same as the sort in your directory ? Are they all RGB with same channels count frames ?

Comment: Your video is H264 encoded, so it makes sense that the frame to frame comparison results in different values.

And what do you mean by frame size is double? The resolution?

Comment: @lamourettejean-baptiste frame size is same i.e 640* 360*3.  I am talking about space that frame is taking. original images are around 100 KB per images whereas after I convert them to video and extract frames each frame is around 200 KB. what additional information is there

Comment: @IbrahimYousuf yes I understand that but i have tried encoding in MJPG and XVID both gave me same results regarding difference between original frame and video extracted frame.

Answer (score 0):

## It's not a fair comparison.

Your original input may have been appropriate for PNG and therefore efficiently compressed.

Your actual encoding options are not shown but you are most likely experiencing [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss) due to using a lossy format. The images are permanently altered with encoding artifacts. These encoding artifacts are due to the methods that help make videos small in file size. While watching the video they are designed to be harder to notice. However, re-encoding from H.264 back to PNG must include these noisy artifacts in the new images which increases the complexity, makes compression harder, and therefore increases the file size. PNG doesn't do well with noise.

Secondly, RGB to YUV colorspace conversion is occurring which can also cause differences.